# OS X Yosemite. How to block internet access for specific app? (AppStore for example)

Tags: macos, mac, firewall, osx-yosemite

How to block internet access for specific app (AppStore for example) in OS X Yosemite, via CLI or GUI?

Comment: if the app has app-specific proxy settings, instead of using global settings, you could set the proxy to be localhost, thereby preventing it from connecting to anything

Answer (score 1):

A paid option is [Little Snitch](https://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch) (€29.95), a network monitor for OS X.

Comment: LittleSnitch is only for outgoing traffic, but a really great choice!

Comment: Little Snitch has been for incoming & outgoing traffic since v3